# Anchor Tag Not working

Tags: html, css

This is killing me for hours. Just a simple Anchor tag is not working.

```
<div id="navigator">
    <div class="show">
        <span><a href="?page_id=28">PORTFOLIO</a></span><span class="carat"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Wherever I am trying to put an anchor tag, its not working

CSS is :

```
#navigator {
position: fixed;
top: 199px;
left: 0;
}
```

The page is here.. http://myingage.com/?page_id=25

Comment: What do you mean it's not working ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `z-index` in `#navigator` in style.css,

```
    #navigator {
        display: none;
        font-family: 'Titillium Web',sans-serif;
        left: 0;
        position: fixed;
        top: 199px;
        z-index: 100;
    }
```

Comment: That Simple.. I must be dumb :(

Comment: not sure how my navigator went behind, but z-index solution resolved it.

Answer (score 5):

your `navigator` is behind the page

just add `z-index: 1000` (anything bigger than z-index of your content) or move your navigator code behind the code of content

Answer (score 1):

try giving a higher z-index
This works for me.

```
#navigator {
position: fixed;
top: 199px;
left: 0;
z-index: 10001;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) CSS property of the parent element was set to `none`. Changing it to `pointer-events: auto` fixed the issue.